# dynamic drop down ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here I am trying use this method to show dynamic drop down from ajax success code is below:

```
 success: function (data) {
    for (var i in data) {
      console.log(data[i].CompanyID + ',' + data[i].clientidSele + ',' + data[i].CompanyName);
      document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = '<select>' + data[i].CompanyName + '</select>';
    }
 }
```

Been trying to append it to the html format but only shows last value other is not shown `document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML` it is used in select tag.

Comment: Can you use `<option>` rather than `<select>` tag? You are modifying the innerHTML

Comment: Worked but it shows only last value other is not shown

Comment: Yeah, but you should do `+=`

Comment: @rinki if the solution is working for you then you may vote up so that it helps others for the similar kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not concate the html.

Please modify your code:

```
success: function (data) {
var selectHtml = "<select>";

for (var i in data) {

    console.log(data[i].CompanyID + ',' + data[i].clientidSele + ',' + data[i].CompanyName);

     selectHtml += '<option value="' + data[i].CompanyID + '">' + data[i].CompanyName + '</option>';
 }

 selectHtml += '</select>';

document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = selectHtml ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` in `document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML +=` in assaignment

```
success: function (data) {
    var drop_down_option ='<select>';
    for (var i in data) {
        console.log(data[i].CompanyID + ',' + data[i].clientidSele + ',' + data[i].CompanyName);
        drop_down_option += '<option>' + data[i].CompanyName + '</option>';
     }
     drop_down_option += '</select>';
 document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = drop_down_option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first at jquery library file .
i hope you will understand what i have done.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

success: function (data) {
    var result="<select>";
    $(data).each(function(index,value)){
        result+="<option value='" + value.CompanyID + "'>"+value.CompanyName+"</option>"
    }
    result+="</select>";
    $("#dropDown").html(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `<option>` tag since you are inserting into `innerHTML` of `<select>` tag already, also you should be using

```
...innerHTML += '<option>' + data[i].CompanyName + '</option>';
```

since `=` would overwrite the previous one in every iteration.